# error sharing static data with constraints

Tags: rust

I'm trying to define static non-mutable data, to use them in AVR's flash memory (hence static), but I'm stuck on this case (this is a resume).

```
trait MenuOption {
    fn get_title(&self) -> String;
}

struct Op<'a> {
    title: &'a str,
}

impl MenuOption for Op<'static> {
    fn get_title(&self) -> String {
        self.title.to_string()
    }
}

struct Menu<'a> {
    options: &'a [&'a MenuOption],
}

static MAIN_MENU: Menu = Menu {
    options: &[&Op { title: "Op1" }],
};

fn main() {}
```

This code gives me this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `MenuOption + 'static: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied in `Menu<'static>`
  --> src/main.rs:19:1
   |
19 | / static MAIN_MENU: Menu = Menu {
20 | |     options: &[&Op { title: "Op1" }],
21 | | };
   | |__^ `MenuOption + 'static` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `Menu<'static>`, the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `MenuOption + 'static`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `&'static MenuOption + 'static`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[&'static MenuOption + 'static]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `&'static [&'static MenuOption + 'static]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Menu<'static>`
   = note: shared static variables must have a type that implements `Sync`
```

I can solve this either by declaring `MAIN_MENU` as `const` instead of `static`, or by defining `Menu::options` as `&'a [&'a Op<'a>]`

Using the struct `Op` I want to use the constraint `MenuOption`.

At this point I'm a bit confused. Whats the problem of sharing non-mutable data? This is probably not related to the data being non-mutable but related to using the constraint.

Can this be done without making `MAIN_MENU` a `const`? Is it OK to use `const`? I know this won't have a fixed allocation but instead the compiler will inject the data as needed.

Comment: Please feel free to come hang out with us in the [avr-rust gitter channel](https://gitter.im/avr-rust/Lobby).

Comment: The duplicates answer [applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5b0ae312cb0f19fc0bcd40a3d7de37b1&version=stable).

Comment: Your type `Menu` does not guarantee that the *trait object* `&MenuOption` implements `Sync`, so there's no guarantee that an arbitrary `Menu` can be stored in static storage.